# Java: Algorithm to place all possible combinations of a set of Integers in a list of matrices

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, combinations, permutation

I am trying to develop a program that given a set of nodes and a set of people both have Integers as a key.

I need to find all possibles comnbinations for the people to go through all the nodes. A single person can go to all the nodes by itself or can be divided by different people.

As the people are homogeneous two people go to through the same nodes in the same order it would be counted only as one solution.

For example Sol: Person 0= [1], Person1= [2], and Person 2= [3] will be equivalent to Sol: Person 0 = [2], Person 1 = [1] and Person 2 = [3] or Sol: Person 0= [1], Person 1= [3, 2], Person 2= null will be equivalent to Sol: , Person 1= [3, 2],Person 1= null ,Person 2= [1].

I use a list of integer matrix Sol to store all possible paths Integer[person][nodes]. So I want to store the solution in either a set or List. That would be Set or List.

So the Sol[0]= will be equal to all the nodes that person number 0 goes through.

If we have 3 persons(0,1,2) and 3(1,2,3) nodes all possible solutions will be:

```
> Sol 1: 
Person 0= [1]
Person 1= [2]
Person 2= [3]


>Sol 2: 
Person 0= [3]
Person 1= [2, 1]
Person 2= null

>Sol 3: 
Person 0= [3]
Person 1= [1, 2]
Person 2= null

>Sol 4: 
Person 0= [1]
Person 1= [3, 2]
Person 2= null

>Sol 5: 
Person 0 = [1]
Person 1= [2, 3]
Person 2= null

>Sol 6: 
Person 0 = [2]
Person 1= [1, 3]
Person 2= null

>Sol 7: 
Person 0 = [2]
Person 1= [3, 1]
Person 2= null

>Sol 8: 
Person 0 = [3, 2, 1]
Person 1= null
Person 2= null

>Sol 9: 
Person 0 = [1, 2, 3]
Person 1= null
Person 2= null

>Sol 10: 
Person 0 = [3, 1, 2]
Person 1= null
Person 2= null

>Sol 11: 
Person 0 = [2, 1, 3]
Person 1= null
Person 2= null

>Sol 12: 
Person 0 = [1, 3, 2]
Person 1= null
Person 2= null

>Sol 13: 
Person 0 = [2, 3, 1]
Person 1= null
Person 2= null
```

Facing the problem my starting idea was to begin adding all the paths for the person 0  using all the nodes, the taking all the nodes except 1 from the path of the person 0 and adding to the person 1, then the taking all the nodes except 1 from the person 0 and add them to the person 1.. and so on.

Then I would call the same function used to generate the paths from Person 0 and Person 1 combined and call it for Person 1 (with the paths generated before) and Person 2. So it would be ideal for a recursive algortihm (in my opinion).

I got all the possible solutions when I have two people, and I am stuck how to implement it for a unlimited number of people and nodes.

Code:

```
public static void function(List<Sol> solutions, int startingPerson, Integer[] people, List<Integer> Numbers, Sol part) {
    Set<List<Integer>> result;
    Set<List<Integer>> resResult;
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer j = Numbers.size(); j >= 0; j--) {

        if (j == 1 && Numbers.size() <= people.length) {

            for (int l = startingPerson; l < Numbers.size() + startingPerson; l++) {
                Integer[] in2 = new Integer[1];
                in2[0] = Numbers.get(l - startingPerson);
                part.getSol()[l] = in2;
            }

            Arrays.fill(part.getSol(), null);
            solutions.add(org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone(part));
            Arrays.fill(part.getSol(), null);

        }


        /*We get all combinations (order not important) of a certain number of the nodes*/
        Combinations it = new Combinations(Numbers, i);
        Iterator<List<Integer>> s = it.iterator();
        Set<List<Integer>> l2 = new HashSet<>();
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            List<Integer> listares = s.next();
            l2.add(listares);
        }
                /*In l2 we have all the combination so loop them to add them to the paths*/
        for (List<Integer> l3 : l2) {
                    /*We get all possible permutations for the numbers of the combination */
            result = permute(l3);
                    /*We loop all possible permutations*/
            for (List<Integer> l4 : result) {
                int k = startingPerson;
                ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(Numbers);
                res.removeAll(l4);

                Integer[] array = new Integer[l4.size()];
                l4.toArray(array);

                //*We get all the permutations from res numbers*//
                resResult = permute(res);

                //*So we won't repeat same paths*//
                if (!res.isEmpty() && (res.size() <= Math.nextUp(Numbers.size() / 2))) {
                    for (List<Integer> l5 : resResult) {
                        Integer[] array2 = new Integer[l5.size()];
                        l5.toArray(array2);
                        part.getSol()[k] = array2;

                    }

                }

                /*Means that we are only using a person to go through all the nodes*/
                if (res.isEmpty()) {

                    part.getSol()[k] = array;
                    solutions.add(org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone(part));
                    Arrays.fill(part.getSol(),null);

                /*More than one person to go through the nodes*/
                } else if (res.size() <= Math.nextUp(Numbers.size() / 2)) {

                    part.getSol()[k + 1] = array;
                    solutions.add(org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone(part));
                    part.getSol()[k + 1] = null;
                    k++;
                        /*We only can take numbers from the combination if we have more than one element */
                        /*if(array.length>1) {
                            function(solutions, k, people, l4, part);
                        }*/


                }


            }


        }
        i++;
    }


}

    public static Set<List<Integer>> permute(List<Integer> ls) {
        // we use a Set of Sets rather than a list of arrays
        // because Sets support adding in the middle
        // and track current length
        Set<List<Integer>> permutations = new HashSet<>();
        // Add an empty Set so that the middle for loop runs
        permutations.add(new ArrayList<>());

        for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
            // create a temporary container to hold the new permutations
            // while we iterate over the old ones
            Set<List<Integer>> current = new HashSet<>();
            for (List<Integer> permutation : permutations) {
                for (int j = 0, n = permutation.size() + 1; j < n; j++) {
                    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(permutation);
                    temp.add(j, ls.get(i));
                    current.add(temp);
                }
            }
            permutations = new HashSet<>(current);
        }

        return permutations;
    }


public class Combinations implements Iterable<List<Integer>> {
    private List<Integer> lista;
    private Integer k;

    public Combinations(List<Integer> s, Integer k) {
        lista = s;
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator() {

        return new IteratorCombn(lista, k);
    }

    private class IteratorCombn implements Iterator<List<Integer>> {
        private int actualSize, maxresult;
        private Integer curIndex;
        private Integer[] result;
        private int[] indices;
        private Integer[] arrayList;
        private List<Integer> elem = null;

        public IteratorCombn(List<Integer> s, Integer k) {
            actualSize = k;// desde donde
            curIndex = 0;
            maxresult = k;
            arrayList = new Integer[s.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
                arrayList[i] = s.get(i);
            }
            this.result = new Integer[actualSize < s.size() ? actualSize : s.size()];

            indices = new int[result.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                indices[i] = result.length - 2 - i;
            }
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            elem = null;
            while ((elem == null && curIndex != -1)) {
                if(indices.length==0){
                    return false;
                }
                indices[curIndex]++;
                if (indices[curIndex] == (curIndex == 0 ? arrayList.length: indices[curIndex - 1])) {

                    indices[curIndex] = indices.length - curIndex - 2;
                    curIndex--;
                } else {

                    result[curIndex] = arrayList[indices[curIndex]];

                    if (curIndex < indices.length - 1)
                        curIndex++;
                    else {
                        elem = new ArrayList<>(result.length);

                        for (Integer s : result) {
                            elem.add(s);

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            if (elem == null) {
                if (actualSize < maxresult) {
                    actualSize++;
                    this.result = new Integer[actualSize < arrayList.length ? actualSize
                            : arrayList.length];
                    indices = new int[result.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                        indices[i] = result.length - 2 - i;
                    }
                    curIndex = 0;

                    return this.hasNext();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public List<Integer> next() {
            return elem;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

The class Sol is a class only containing a Integer[][] sol

I only use a matrix and I change it all the time because I want to save JVM memory.

I wonder if someone could help me with my approach or give me another idea on how to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that any person can go through zero, or more, or all nodes, the only requirement for a solution is that each node is visited exactly once?

Comment: A person can go through all the nodes, but two people cannot go through the same node. The requirement is that all the nodes are visited by someone. Sorry if I did not express myself well.

Comment: In that case, you're missing a lot of other possible solutions. For example, `person 0 = [2], person 1 = [1] and person 2 = [3]`, or `person 0 = null, person 1 = [3,2] and person 2 = [1]`

Comment: As all the people are homogeneous this sol ( Sol 1: Person 0= [1], Person1= [2], and Person 2= [3] ) will be equivalent to Person 0 = [2], Person 1 = [1] and Person 2 = [3] and the same for the second one to Sol 4:  Person 0= [1] Person 1= [3, 2] Person 2= null

Comment: Look at it like this - each node has a *choice* which person will be the one to visit it. So for `n` persons and `m` nodes, you have `m * n!` possible solutions.

Comment: As it is shown in the code my idea is to make a recursive function! But I am not into recursivity. so I am really having a hard time with the function!

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Read something about backtracking (and you are correct, you will find that a recursive method is a good idea). (2) Define a canonical representation of a solution so that out all solutions that you consider equal, exactly one of them is canonical and is produces by your program, the rest are not (or at least, are not output). (Disclaimer: I have not read through your code, so I may have missed something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my own suggestion from the comment I decided that in a canonical solution all the persons that visit one or more nodes are first, and any persons not visiting any nodes come last. The persons visiting nodes are sorted by the first node they visit. Apart from that I wrote my own solution from scratch rather than using yours. My solution could be made more efficient by pruning the search tree in a few places; but it does print the same 13 solutions that you gave in the question.

```
public class Combine {

    public static final int nNodes = 3;
    public static final int nPersons = 3;

    // nodes
    private Node[] nodes;
    private int nUnvisitedNodes = nNodes;

    // solution
    private Node[][] sol = new Node[nPersons][];

    // no of solutions already found and printed
    int nSolutions = 0;

    public Combine() {
        // init nodes
        nodes = new Node[nNodes];
        for (int nix = 0; nix < nodes.length; nix++) {
            nodes[nix] = new Node(nix + 1); // node names are 1-based
        }

        // search for solutions -- person 0 first
        tryPerson0();
    }

    private void tryPerson0() {
        if (nUnvisitedNodes == 0) { // done
            printSolution();
        } else {
            // assuming this is not the last person, this person may visit 1 through nUnvisitedNodes nodes
            // (in a canonical solution person 0 cannot visit 0 nodes)
            int maxVisits = nUnvisitedNodes;
            for (int nNodesToVisit = 1; nNodesToVisit <= maxVisits; nNodesToVisit++) {
                sol[0] = new Node[nNodesToVisit];
                tryNode(0, sol[0], 0);
                sol[0] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void tryPerson(int person) {
        assert person > 0;
        if (nUnvisitedNodes == 0) { // solution complete
            printSolution();
        } else {
            if (person < nPersons) { // still persons to try
                if (person == nPersons - 1) { // this is the last person
                    // person must visit all remaining nodes
                    // in a canonical solution, first node must be greater than first node visited by previous person
                    int nNodesToVisit = nUnvisitedNodes;
                    sol[person] = new Node[nNodesToVisit];
                    tryNodeWithMininum(person, sol[person], 0, sol[person - 1][0].name + 1);
                    sol[person] = null;
                } else {
                    // since this is not the last person, this person may visit 1 through nUnvisitedNodes nodes
                    // in a canonical solution, first node must be greater than first node visited by previous person
                    int maxVisits = nUnvisitedNodes;
                    for (int nNodesToVisit = 1; nNodesToVisit <= maxVisits; nNodesToVisit++) {
                        sol[person] = new Node[nNodesToVisit];
                        tryNodeWithMininum(person, sol[person], 0, sol[person - 1][0].name + 1);
                        sol[person] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void tryNode(int person, Node[] personSol, int nix) {
        if (nix == personSol.length) { // this person's solution complete
            tryPerson(person + 1);
        } else {
            for (Node candidateNode : nodes) {
                if (candidateNode.visit()) {
                    personSol[nix] = candidateNode;
                    tryNode(person, personSol, nix + 1);
                    personSol[nix] = null;
                    candidateNode.unvisit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void tryNodeWithMininum(int person, Node[] personSol, int nix, int minNodeName) {
        for (Node candidateNode : nodes) {
            if (candidateNode.getName() >= minNodeName) {
                if (candidateNode.visit()) {
                    personSol[nix] = candidateNode;
                    tryNode(person, personSol, nix + 1);
                    personSol[nix] = null;
                    candidateNode.unvisit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void printSolution() {
        nSolutions++;
        System.out.println("> Sol " + nSolutions);
        for (int pix = 0; pix < nodes.length; pix++) {
            System.out.println("Person " + pix + " = " + Arrays.toString(sol[pix]));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Combine();
    }

    private class Node {
        int name;
        boolean visited = false;

        public Node(int name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        /** visits node if not already visited */
        public boolean visit() {
            if (visited) {
                return false;
            } else {
                visited = true;
                nUnvisitedNodes--;
                return true;
            }
        }

        /** undoes visit (that is, backtracks) */
        public void unvisit() {
            assert visited : name;
            nUnvisitedNodes++;
            visited = false;
        }

        public int getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(name);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it is a good one!! But I want to store all the solutions in a list instead of printing them. How would it be possible as wiht the recursion the list will end up empty!

Comment: Declare a list of solutions after the `sol` variable. Rename `printSolution()` to, say, `saveSolution`, and inside it add a copy of the solution to the list instead of printing it (copying it at that point will ensure it doesn’t end up empty). Does this get you going? If it’s not enough, post your attempt in a new question and tell us what you’re still missing.

Comment: I got the solution adding the to the list the clone of the sol. But I need to think to store it in a different way because when we have many nodes and many people it gives an error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space indicating that the java virtual machine ran out of memory.

Comment: That probably happens because of the recursion, not because you’re saving too many results. You can try increasing heap space as a first step, but there are limits to that.

Comment: Is it because I am saving too many results? My idea was to add all the results to a file. And then read them. I've already increased the heap space, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I am changing my mind, but not sure. The recursion probably eats more stack space than heap space, and only roughly proportional to the number of nodes. The list of solutions takes heap space and grows more than linearly in number of nodes and number of persons, so this could well be the culprit. Writing the solutions to a file is certainly worth trying.